# How to show sum of all columns 'Total' row at top of all rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Sample Data:

```
LocationCode    Name      NetSalesQty
01              holsale   24
B1              bhk vyas  24
d001            retail    24
Total           NULL      72
```

I want records with a fixed Total row at the top as follows:

```
LocationCode    Name      NetSalesQty
Total           NULL      72
01              holsale   24
B1              bhk vyas  24
d001            retail    24
```

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(LocationMaster.LocationCode, 'Total') AS LocationCode,
       LocationMaster.Name,
       SUM(IdTableExtd.DocQty * IdTableExtd.StockSign) AS NetSalesQty
FROM IdTable
     INNER JOIN LocationMaster ON LocationMaster.LocationCode = IdTable.LocationCode
     INNER JOIN IdTableExtd ON IdTableExtd.LocationCode = IdTable.LocationCode    AND IdTableExtd.StockNo = IdTable.StockNo
WHERE IdTableExtd.DocDate BETWEEN '2018-10-07 ' AND '2018-10-10 '
GROUP BY ROLLUP(LocationMaster.LocationCode, LocationMaster.Name);
```

Comment: Is `Total` actually part of your data, and if not, what query is generating this output?

Comment: `ORDER BY GROUPING_ID(YourColumn) DESC`?

Comment: @PHPDEVLOPER Comments are not the right place for information that belongs in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by` clause :

```
select t.*
from table t
order by (case when name is null then 0 else 1 end), LocationCode;
```